# Having trouble with scrolldown

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble with the scrolldown when clicking on the navigation menu. The scrolldown works perfectly on the home page. After going to any of the pages, when I click on any of the menu links it goes to the home page,not to particluar location, the scrolldown is not working for the menu. I tried the `animate()` function:

```
if(window.location.hash.length>0){
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#latest-offers').offset().top}, 800);
    }
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: what theme you are using?

Comment: Auto Image - Wordpress Car Dealer theme

Comment: Have you created menus from the admin panel?

Comment: yes,i also tried to give custom links also but not working

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: creativeexpertindia.com/olympic/

Comment: As I tested, All your menus are working fine except creativeexpertindia.com/olympic/#contact. Am I right? I checked in chrome browser

Comment: yes its working on the home page,did check it after going to warrenty or tecnology pages.from there if u click on the menu links it just going to the home page.the scrolling is not working from the static pages

Comment: Check your theme-options for menu links

Comment: i check for menu links in theme options but its not thre.